# Trace logging from WPF XBAP application

Tags: c#, wpf, xbap

I have an issue with an XBAP application that only occurs on one users machine when they run the deployed XBAP. I cannot reproduce the error either on my machine with the XBAP or through Visual studio. What I need is to add debug trace statements to the code, deploy a "Trace" version to a test environment and get the user to try this to figure out exactly where the error is occurring. However I can't seem to find any information on how to create a log from an XBAP application. I understand this is to do with partial/full trust issues, but assuming this is a partial trust scenario - what options do I have for getting debug trace information out of the application at runtime?

Comment: I agree with toadflakz under, you need proper logging. Just remember that it has to go somewhere in the users **%Appdata%** folder. I've been working with really large LOB XBAP applications over the last years, and believe me, you can not live without proper logging :) BTW: Tip beware of presentationhost.exe, you should check in your code if more than one is running. It hangs all the time, and your problem may be as simple as that, even though I don't know your application. Another one if you are running fulltrust and have a test cert, remember to install it in trustet root, t. p. and personal

Comment: Can you start the client application? Or do you get a trust not granted or similar error before starting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest marking your application up to use log4net as it has maximum flexibility with how trace messages can be logged. It should be able to run in the type of environment you are working with, using one of the options available.

More info at: [Log4net Features](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/features.html)